# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure - Issue while accessing stored procedure in different schema

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, connection-string

I can see below error while starting one of the windows service.I am seeing error in one of the web application hosted in same server also.Both are connecting to same database.It was working without any issue for last two years and suddenly appearing these errors in event viewer

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 
 'psp_SDT_SRV_Insert'.
```

Issue happens while connection stored procedure inside 'dgo' schema only.But I can access all procedures inside 'dbo' schema.

When i tried created Windows Form application and trying to access the same SP,i didn't face any issue.All these apps using same connection string

Connection string is as follows

```
  <add name="connectionstring" connectionString="server=PGSI.PA.YA.NET\INST1;database=CustomerDB;integrated security = true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Can anyone advice how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Schema qualify the object name in the sql statement. Example: `dgo.psp_SDT_SRV_Insert`

Comment: .It was working without any issue for last two years and suddenly appearing these errors in event viewer.I didn't made any code change recently

Comment: It was working without any issue for last two years and suddenly appearing these errors in event viewer.I am really surprised

Comment: You can also change the owned schema for the user/login or the default schema in the database in Sql Server (if you do not want to make code changes).

Comment: Something changed you just might not realize what changed and when. Either on Sql Server with your login, in the database properties, the connection string, or in the code. Errors occur for a reason. If everything was working without errors and then later errors start occurring then something changed.

Comment: But i have other strored procedures which are in dbo schema.But i didn't get why need a code fix. Because it was working in production for last two year without any issue and suddenly this issue popup

Comment: In db side what all i need to check to verify ??

Comment: Have you set "cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;"?

Comment: This can happen if the default schema of the user is changed. Because this is using integrated security, we can't see from the information provided here which user that actually is. Is there actually a `dgo` schema and does it serve a purpose? Because it sounds like a simple typo for `dbo`. Try a `select * from customerDB.sys.database_principals where default_schema_name='dgo'`.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert ..yes ..i have one schema named 'dgo'.i will check that possibility whether dgo is default schema for that user

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert ..Thank u so much for pointing it in right direction.Even if dgo is default schema there are some other parameter overriding this..Finally it worked  ..https://serverfault.com/questions/203551/sql-server-2008-default-schema-not-being-respected

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because the default schema settings.So, in order to have a default schema a user needs to have database roles like db_owner, db_datawriter and so on, instead of server role sysadmin.
I have resolved with the help of below thread

https://serverfault.com/questions/203551/sql-server-2008-default-schema-not-being-respected